# Where to get mapmaking software for Mac?

Tags: tool-recommendation, map-making

I've been looking for a program that can create maps on a Mac... Any ideas? I would like it to be a World Map, that the players just relate to, to know where they are and to tie all of the quests into one story. Also as a side note, I'm not skilled at GIMP or Photoshop, so I would rather not go on that approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nearly all mapmaking software aimed at RPGs is exclusively for Windows, which makes it hard for GMs who are Mac owners to find anything to create maps, if they don't have the technical and artistic skills that mapmaking with a photo-editing suite requires.

The one RPG mapping tool I've used to good effect that is available on Mac is [Hexographer](http://www.hexographer.com/). (It's Java, so runs everywhere Java is installed, which includes Macs.) I've used its free verson to create world maps before, and it does the job well enough. It creates hex maps though, so its maps are not pretty by modern standards (unless you like the aesthetic of hex maps!), but for your purposes will convey the information you need to your players.

Answer (score 1):

When I saw the question I immediately thought of [Hexographer](http://www.hexographer.com/).

I use it on a Windows PC and Linux (runs under Java, so should also work on Mac). The free version has good random map generation, but also a good choice of tiles to create your own from scratch.

The paid version lets you zoom in on a hex (or range of hexes) to add more detail to a specific area, also an option to import an image (such as an outline map) and draw on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

[Ortelius](http://www.mapdiva.com/ortelius/) by MapDiva is I believe the best map-making app out there right now for mac. Version 2 is apparently right around the corner.

Comment: That looks awesome.  I'm going to have to check it out when I get home.  However, it's worth noting that this is *professional* cartography software with a matching price ($99).

Comment: Submitted as an edit by an anon but should have been a comment: "Update: After watching their website and forums for the past 6+ months I've seen very little development or forum usage. Version 2 apparently won't be put out until 2015 though at this point I'm wondering if at all. It looks great, but at the price point I'd tread carefully."

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a cool world map, donjon has a [generic world generator](http://donjon.bin.sh/world/) that works pretty good and runs online (you can easily export the maps, though).  If you happen to be running a fantasy campaign or one of a handful of scifi systems there are slightly enhanced generators available on that site as well.  All of the stuff is free, and takes basically no time or effort to use, which is pretty sweet.